# Java Jackson Deserialize Array of mixed datatype

Tags: java, arrays, json

How to deserialize array of mixed datatype string to java class using jackson. Here is input string. if you see candles, the inner array is mix of date string, double and int values.

```
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "candles": [
        ["2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530", 1386.4, 1388, 1381.05, 1385.1, 788],
        ["2015-12-28T09:16:00+0530", 1385.1, 1389.1, 1383.85, 1385.5, 609],
        ["2015-12-28T09:17:00+0530", 1385.5, 1387, 1385.5, 1385.7, 212],
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for your question? I'm also looking for the same.